# multiprocess in python: cross process to process watch-kill-restart

Tags: python, multiprocessing, restart, watch

Want to make a  "cross-life" control on two processes started by the same parent.

If process A take too long to change a value on the Read list of process B, process B should kill and restart A, and reverse also is true.

This is how process are launched from parent:

```
def check():
    ....# ok check the value in the R list
    #kill and restart

def A:
    check()#kill and restart B if something goes wrong
    #... do his homework


def B:
    check()#kill and restart A if something goes wrong
    #... do his homework

job1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=A, args=(R,W))
job2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=B, args=(W,R))


procs = []
procs.append(job1)
procs.append(job2)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    _start = time.time()
    map(lambda x: x.start(), procs)                                
    #job1.terminate() it kill the process but can't call it from inside A or B
    map(lambda x: x.join(), procs)
```

Both A and B have a call (and this work) to a function that is defined in the parent and look for the changes in the list but how can I call the terminate() and run() from that function that run inside of the processes so can't know the name, pid of the other process?

Comment: Are you sure you wanna do this? This is breaking rules of safe and reliable concurrent programming. If you launch two processes from _supervisor_ use it as a mediator between A and B. You can create something like *watchdog* or send message from A to _supervisor_, that B don't reply.

Comment: Supervisor seems to be interesting but it seems to be unable to run under python 3, I need to build an application without use of external source as far as I can. About the watchdog you mean to write new cod that send a special value in the exchange list to trigger the process  kill from inside? or there is already watchdog function in multiprocessing?

Comment: I mean to code something on your own, as `multiprocessing` has mechanics for inter-process communication.

Comment: ok, I don't ask the code, I'm asking if someone with better experience than me can suggest "a best practice" steps to do it. Mean is better that the watch is handled inside A and B or by the parent? or another process that only do the check?

Comment: By parent. As probably parent will no nothing else than waiting for those to to finish the job.

Comment: I've turned A and B in classes and added a shutdownrestart method that kill the failing process but after this if I try A.start() or A.run() this error appear 'cannot start a process twice'.

Answer (score 0):

If I kill a process that share a list with multiprocessing.Manager is there a way to i.e. set all values to "0" and prevent the crash of others programs that will look for the same shared list?

This is the output in console if I kill the process that share the list and then restart it:

```
parent process: 19416
process id: 19500
[DEBUG/gigi-5:20] thread 'MainThread' does not own a connection
[DEBUG/gigi-5:20] making connection to manager
[DEBUG/gigi-5:20] failed to connect to address /tmp/pymp-0HGU9Z/listener-HVxKEA
[INFO/gigi-5:20] process shutting down
[DEBUG/gigi-5:20] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/gigi-5:20] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
Process Pippo-5:20:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/gigi/TESTCOM/gigi.py", line 62, in run
    COM.pid2.value=COM.info('gigi')                                  # assegna a pid1 il PID del processo
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1040, in set
    return self._callmethod('set', (value,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 755, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 742, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 169, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 297, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[INFO/gigi-5:20] process exiting with exitcode 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I've enabled Debug functions, and tried to kill and restart child processes from the parent.

I've turned A and B in classes and added a shutdown method that kill the failing process, after this, if I try A.start() or A.run() this error appear 'cannot start a process twice'.What this means? the process is dead, there aren't others running.

If I call multiprocessing.active_childre() the process aren't restarted but got this output:

```
 <Process(SyncManager-2, started)>, <Process(SyncManager-1, started)>, <Process(SyncManager-3, started)>]
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] calling <Finalize object, callback=_decref, args=(Token(typeid='Value', address='/tmp/pymp-2ObnP1/listener-aIRbnG', id='7f28db9b6190'), '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28db9a6718>, <multiprocessing.util.ForkAwareLocal object at 0x7f28db98da10>, ProcessLocalSet(['7f28db9b6190']), <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>), exitprority=10>
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function _decref at 0x7f28db99faa0> with args (Token(typeid='Value', address='/tmp/pymp-2ObnP1/listener-aIRbnG', id='7f28db9b6190'), '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28db9a6718>, <multiprocessing.util.ForkAwareLocal object at 0x7f28db98da10>, ProcessLocalSet(['7f28db9b6190']), <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>) and kwargs {}
[DEBUG/MainProcess] DECREF '7f28db9b6190'
[DEBUG/MainProcess] thread 'Dummy-1' has no more proxies so closing conn
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] calling <Finalize object, callback=_decref, args=(Token(typeid='Value', address='/tmp/pymp-EfUPHj/listener-hPdyzk', id='7f28db9b30d0'), '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28db9a6638>, <multiprocessing.util.ForkAwareLocal object at 0x7f28db98d9a8>, ProcessLocalSet(['7f28db9b30d0']), <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>), exitprority=10>
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function _decref at 0x7f28db99faa0> with args (Token(typeid='Value', address='/tmp/pymp-EfUPHj/listener-hPdyzk', id='7f28db9b30d0'), '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28db9a6638>, <multiprocessing.util.ForkAwareLocal object at 0x7f28db98d9a8>, ProcessLocalSet(['7f28db9b30d0']), <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>) and kwargs {}
[DEBUG/MainProcess] DECREF '7f28db9b30d0'
[DEBUG/MainProcess] thread 'Dummy-1' has no more proxies so closing conn
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] calling <Finalize object, callback=_decref, args=(Token(typeid='list', address='/tmp/pymp-W6FZ5G/listener-V4fUuw', id='7f28db9b3908'), '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28ddc2f7f8>, <multiprocessing.util.ForkAwareLocal object at 0x7f28db98d940>, ProcessLocalSet(['7f28db9acf38', '7f28db9b3908']), <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>), exitprority=10>
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function _decref at 0x7f28db99faa0> with args (Token(typeid='list', address='/tmp/pymp-W6FZ5G/listener-V4fUuw', id='7f28db9b3908'), '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28ddc2f7f8>, <multiprocessing.util.ForkAwareLocal object at 0x7f28db98d940>, ProcessLocalSet(['7f28db9acf38', '7f28db9b3908']), <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>) and kwargs {}
[DEBUG/MainProcess] DECREF '7f28db9b3908'
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] calling <Finalize object, callback=_decref, args=(Token(typeid='list', address='/tmp/pymp-W6FZ5G/listener-V4fUuw', id='7f28db9acf38'), '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28ddc2f7f8>, <multiprocessing.util.ForkAwareLocal object at 0x7f28db98d940>, ProcessLocalSet(['7f28db9acf38']), <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>), exitprority=10>
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function _decref at 0x7f28db99faa0> with args (Token(typeid='list', address='/tmp/pymp-W6FZ5G/listener-V4fUuw', id='7f28db9acf38'), '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28ddc2f7f8>, <multiprocessing.util.ForkAwareLocal object at 0x7f28db98d940>, ProcessLocalSet(['7f28db9acf38']), <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>) and kwargs {}
[DEBUG/MainProcess] DECREF '7f28db9acf38'
[DEBUG/MainProcess] thread 'Dummy-1' has no more proxies so closing conn
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] calling <Finalize object, callback=_finalize_manager, args=(<Process(SyncManager-3, started)>, '/tmp/pymp-2ObnP1/listener-aIRbnG', '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28db9a6718>, <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>), exitprority=0>
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function _finalize_manager at 0x7f28db99f5f0> with args (<Process(SyncManager-3, started)>, '/tmp/pymp-2ObnP1/listener-aIRbnG', '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28db9a6718>, <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>) and kwargs {}
[INFO/MainProcess] sending shutdown message to manager
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] calling <Finalize object, callback=_finalize_manager, args=(<Process(SyncManager-2, started)>, '/tmp/pymp-EfUPHj/listener-hPdyzk', '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28db9a6638>, <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>), exitprority=0>
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function _finalize_manager at 0x7f28db99f5f0> with args (<Process(SyncManager-2, started)>, '/tmp/pymp-EfUPHj/listener-hPdyzk', '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28db9a6638>, <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>) and kwargs {}
[INFO/MainProcess] sending shutdown message to manager
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] calling <Finalize object, callback=_finalize_manager, args=(<Process(SyncManager-1, started)>, '/tmp/pymp-W6FZ5G/listener-V4fUuw', '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28ddc2f7f8>, <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>), exitprority=0>
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] finalizer calling <function _finalize_manager at 0x7f28db99f5f0> with args (<Process(SyncManager-1, started)>, '/tmp/pymp-W6FZ5G/listener-V4fUuw', '\xc0\xad;K\xce2\xb1\x0f\x17\xe4|f\x14\x1a\x11\xc0\x89 n\x00\x00.\x19B0\xcd%\xac \x83\x8e\x87', <multiprocessing.managers.State object at 0x7f28ddc2f7f8>, <function Client at 0x7f28db99b9b0>) and kwargs {}
[INFO/MainProcess] sending shutdown message to manager
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
```